# Please advice windows mobile device with a barcode scanner for .NET

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, barcode

I need to find a windows mobile device that has a barcode scanner built in or attached. It's important that I can use the barcode scanner from the .NET compact framework application. Also, the device's price should not exceed $300. Please advice if you used something similar in your projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Intermec, Symbol/Motorla and Honeywell all make handheld barcode scanners that run either Windows CE or Windows Mobile, so they would run Compact Framework applications.  They both have SDKs to allow affecting the barcode scanner - though typically you can just use them as-is and the scan data comes in as if it were typed on the keyboard.

Your price-point, however, is unrealistic.  You can hardly get a consumer-grade, general, high-volume Windows Mobile device for $300.  You certainly won't find a low-volume, hardened device with a barcode scanner in it for that price - it will be more like $1,000 ( a bit less if you're willing to take an older, monochrome display).  You might find one on eBay, for a lower price, but even there I doubt you'd find one for $300 that was in working condition.

There are several online vendors for these devices, so a web search should be your next stop.  The term you probably are looking for is "Portable Data Terminal".  For example searching on "portable data terminal barcode scanner" or "windows ce barcode scanner" turned up loads of prospects.